# Xcode custom control via storyboard

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, uiview, storyboard

I want to use a custom control in my project, specifically a horizontal picker view I found on cocoacontrols.com (http://cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/cppickerview). I've been able to include it into my project, load data and it works very nicely.

The pickerView is setted up programatically on viewDidLoad but I'd really like to be able to use it via storyboards because I'm a using static tableView. I tried to add a UIView, set the class to the PickerView class and then set up the outlet. I builds without errors or warnings but the picker view does not appear. It only shows a white rectangle.

Anyone with experience in this? Is it possible at all or should I keep it programatically?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, that's normal. CPPickerView does not seem to implement `initWithCoder:`... I only see an `initWithFrame:` in the [source code](https://github.com/cbpowell/CPPickerView/blob/master/PickerView/CPPickerView/CPPickerView.m), which obviously means you can only instantiate that custom UIView from code. Or you can change CPPickerView's implementation to support what you want. It's open source.

Comment: oh, thanks! I´ll take it into account next time I need something like this.